# Android Webview: Smaller Display Size Breaks Layout

Tags: android, css, webview, android-webview

I have an web app that's basically just displaying mobile website in an Android Webview, with some native bits for handling notification & navigation headers.

The issue is, when I change the `Display Size` setting (under Display) in an Android phone to anything smaller than `Default`, the content will be squeezed to the right side and left a blank space. I did a check with dev tool, and somehow the CSS's `width` is set to `66.67%` of parent's by Android (in default it's `100%`) & a minor left padding is also added. However, if the `Display Size` setting is larger than default, there is none / very minor style degradation.

The interesting part is when similar app is made in iOS (just display mobile site), there's no issue at all after changing the `Display Size`. So I'm pretty certain that the fix is limited to Android.

Is there any guidance to add code to anticipate these changes, or at least, completely disable the `Display Size` setting's effects?

*Edit:
What I've tried & failed:

- Setting `"width=device-width, initial-scale=1"` in the website
- Set `loadWithOverviewMode` and `useWideViewPort` to `true`
- Combination of both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple actually: there's a piece of old CSS code in the website that overrides CSS values when the width of the display is above certain threshold.